# Can I write "The modernizing São Paulo"

Tags: grammar

If I want to say that São Paulo is going through a modernization process, can I say my story happens "in the context of the modernizing São Paulo"? I was trying to avoid using "in the context of the modernization of São Paulo".. for some reason it didn't sound good. Thanks!

Comment: “My/the story is ***set*** in modern-day São Paulo / between the years X and Y / during the X period” I wouldn't use "in the context" as you have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say it, but it may not mean what you want. I’ll add some extra words so it makes the difference clearer:

1. Substantive use: In the context of **modernizing** São Paulo as quickly as possible. . . .
2. Adjectival use: In the context of a rapidly **modernizing** São Paulo. . . .
3. Participial use: **Modernizing** itself more and more every day, nowadays São Paulo finds itself at the dynamic center of its continent.

To toss some bad Portuguese at you (my apologies!) for what I hope is a clearer comparison, those might run something like:

1. No contexto de **modernizar** São Paulo tão rapidamente quanto possível. . . .
2. No context dum São Paulo **modernizante** e com pressa.
3. **Modernizando**-se mais e mais a cada dia, hoje em dia São Paulo encontra-se no centro dinâmico do seu continente.

The point is that in English, once you include the article *the*, you force *modernizing* into an adjectival role, not a substantive one.  And we have three different kinds of uses of the same word *modernizing* that map to three really completely different sorts of equivalents in Portuguese.

This is probably what is confusing you.

And we haven't even dragged *modernization* / *modernização* into it. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was an attempt to translate an abstract for a dissertation. I had the sentence "no contexto de modernização de São Paulo e laicização republicana" setting the context of the analysis. I think the easiest translation would be "in the context of modernization of São Paulo and republican secularization", and I wanted to try something more "English" like... so the adjectival role sounds good to me, but now I'm wondering, if I say "the modernizing São Paulo", does it mean that São Paulo is modernizing something or modernizing itself? The second should be the option I need...

Comment: You are correct that if you say "the modernizing São Paulo" it is ambiguous whether it is modernizing itself or something else, but usually it would be an intransitive or reflexive sense. This may be one of those somewhat uncommon places where English wants an article even though Portuguese did not demand one. You haven’t said ***da** modernizaçao* or said *e **a** laicização*, but I feel like both those sound better with the article *the* in front of them in English. BTW, I love the word *laicização*! You are right to translate it to *secularization*, for our *laicization* is too rarely used.

Comment: I went with "in the context of the modernizing São Paulo and the republican secularization,...". At the end I think it sounds better in my head! Hahah and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Either you write "the modernizing of Sao Paulo" or "modernizing Sao Paulo".